# ckeditor in django has chenged to TextField

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I was using postgresql and then I had to change my db to mysql . after changing all RichTextUploadingFields changed to TextFields in django admin ! How can I fix this ?

also I try this code in settings.py but It does not working :

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/yeganexu/public_html/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/yeganexu/public_html/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'   

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js' 

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default':
        {
            'toolbar': 'full',
            'width': 'auto',
            'extraPlugins': ','.join([
                'codesnippet',
            ]),
        },
}`
```